# CreateProcess doesn't pass command line argument to new process's main function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have some question about CreateProcess Function.
plz see my cpp files beblow.

```
//CreateProcess.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define DIR_LEN MAX_PATH+1

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USEPOSITION | STARTF_USESIZE;
    si.dwX = 100;
    si.dwY = 200;
    si.dwXSize = 300;
    si.dwYSize = 200;
    si.lpTitle = _T("I am a hummingat");
    TCHAR command[] = _T("AdderProcess.exe AA BB");
    TCHAR cDir[DIR_LEN];
    BOOL state;

    GetCurrentDirectory(DIR_LEN, cDir);
    _fputts(cDir, stdout);
    _fputts(_T("\n"), stdout);

    SetCurrentDirectory(_T("C:\\WinSystem"));

    GetCurrentDirectory(DIR_LEN, cDir);
    _fputts(cDir,stdout);
    _fputts(_T("\n"),stdout);

    state = CreateProcess (
        NULL,
        command,
        NULL, NULL, TRUE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL, NULL, &si, &pi
        );

    if(state !=0)
        _fputts(_T("Creation OK! \n"), stdout);
    else
        _fputts(_T("Creation Error! \n"), stdout);

    _fgettchar();
    return 0;
}


//AdderProcess.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _tprintf( _T ("%s\n", argv[1]));
    _tprintf( _T ("%s\n", argv[2]));

    DWORD val1, val2;
    val1 = _ttoi(argv[1]);
    val2 = _ttoi(argv[2]);

    _tprintf( _T("%d + %d = %d\n", val1, val2, val1+val2));

    _gettchar();

    return 0;
}
```

it was ok that creating AdderProcess console windows after i opened CreateProcess.exe.
    but it has problem about passing main function arguments. argv[1] , argv[2]

this is AdderProcess.exe execution result screen,

```
<null>
<null>
0 + 0 = 234234324 <- trash value
```

i dont know reason why CreateProcess.exe cant pass arguments to AdderProcess.exe

Comment: BTW: Are you porting an ancient windows-only program to NT-based windows? If not, leave `TCHAR` and derived types and macros in the past where they belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the OP didn't quite get why the problem occurred.  The reason is a misuse of the `_T` macro.

Instead of this:

```
_tprintf( _T ("%d + %d = %d\n", val1, val2, val1+val2));
```

It should be this:

```
_tprintf( _T("%d + %d = %d\n"), val1, val2, val1+val2);
```

The same error appears in all of the other lines in `_tmain` that use `_T`.  The `_T` macro takes one argument, and that is a string-literal.

Comment: THX. i got answer for this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at this, from your code:

```
_tprintf( _T ("%d + %d = %d\n", val1, val2, val1+val2));
```

Do you see anything wrong with it?

I'm just directing your attention at one bug, since you're effectively asking readers to *debug your program for you*.

---

Regarding

> **”** i dont know reason why CreateProcess.exe cant pass arguments to AdderProcess.exe

the assemption that the CreateProcess.exe program is to blame, is not necessarily warranted. The bugs in the second program mean that you have no real data. Yet.

Comment: OK, maybe a *hint*: you're using the comma operator.

Comment: `_T` is a macro , so it is the comma separator between macro arguments. Which shouldn't compile since `_T` takes one argument.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I thought as you do, so I concluded comma operator. But as it turns out, MSVC compiles it (though it warns). It just discards the rest. :(

Comment: THX for hint. it works, after i changed all macro and function in tchar.h (_T ,etc) to char type.

Comment: @hummingatpark `it works, after i changed all macro and function in tchar.h (_T ,etc) to char type` - The reason for the problems has nothing to do with changing to a char type.  Your `_T` macro is supposed to work on string literals, i.e. `_T("%d + %d = %d\n")`  Note where the last `)` is located.